# NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER returns null in fragments

Tags: android, locationmanager

### Issue i am facing

`nwLocation` & `gpsLocation` are null at `onStart()`

### Manifest i have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

---

**FrgAddNewJobsLocation.java**(class extends Fragment)

```
@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    initilizeMap();
    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(getActivity());
    nwLocation = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    gpsLocation = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

**AppLocationService.java**

```
public class AppLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60 * 2;

    public AppLocationService(Context context) {

        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public Location getLocation(String provider) {

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
            if (locationManager != null) {

                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                return location;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you put them in onActivityCreted?

Comment: this may seem silly but is location setting enabled on device?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `appLocationService = new AppLocationService(getActivity());`

use:

```
Context mcontext;      
appLocationService = new AppLocationService(mContext);
```

Also check if you have provided internet permission in manifest file